# C Program translation to Assembly (x86_64) on Linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm a newbie to assembly programming (especially x86_64).I have translated the following c program to assembly.

I understood most of the code but I'm not able to interpret the 2 Instructions I've commented out .

***** Isn't the **stmnt 1**  corrupting contents of **rax** register by copying **42** to its lower word ?

**note:**  as per the logic **stmnt 1** should increment **42** in location whose address is stored in **rax**

```
addl $1,(%rax)
```

could some one explain those 2 instructions .

### temp.c

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a=42,*ptr;

        ptr = &a;
        (*ptr)++;

        return 0;
    }
```

### temp.s

```
        .file   "temp.c"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
    main:
    .LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $42, -20(%rbp)
        leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax  
        movl    (%rax), %eax         ;  stmt 1
        leal    1(%rax), %edx        ;  stmt 2
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        movl    $0, %eax
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
        xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
        je  .L3
        call    __stack_chk_fail
    .L3:
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
    .LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `stmt1` is overwriting `rax`, but that is not a problem. `stmt2` is then doing `edx = eax + 1` in a tricky way using `lea`. The incremented value in `edx`  is written back into memory at `movl    %edx, (%rax)`. This means the `(*ptr)++;` has been split into multiple steps like this:

```
rax = ptr;     /* load pointer */
eax = *rax;    /* fetch current value */
edx = eax + 1; /* calculate new value */
rax = ptr;     /* load pointer again */
*rax = edx;    /* write new value */
```

Yes, `addl $1,(%rax)` could have been used. You probably don't have optimization enabled which is why you see inefficient code.

With optimization enabled, the following code:

```
void foo(int* ptr)
{
    (*ptr)++;
}
```

produces this assembly:

```
    addl    $1, (%rdi)
    ret
```

And this:

```
void foo(int* ptr)
{
    *ptr = 42;
    (*ptr)++;
}
```

gives:

```
    movl    $43, (%rdi)
    ret
```

Comment: so **stmnt 2** is synonymous to  these  instructions **addl $1, eax** and **movl eax , edx**

Comment: Yes, except your sequence destroys eax and the flags. A slightly better sequence is `movl %eax, %edx; addl $1, %edx` as that only destroys the flags :)

Comment: now  i'm getting it . **leal** is just working as **movl**  , saying that pretend **eax** content (43) as address and add 1 to it . and move 43 back to edx..

Comment: `leal` is often used instead of `addl`, since it is faster.

Comment: @jester . how to enable Optimization in gcc compiler.  I tried  flags **-O**  and **-O2** on gcc , the assembly output of main()  contains  no instructions except this one instuction -  **mov $1 , eax** (return 0).

Comment: That's how you enable it, but you have to write code that actually does something with the value otherwise the compiler will correctly identify it as something that can be removed. You could `return` it, or `printf` it, for example.